# Correct the sentence

Tags: pronouns, possessives

Are they your books ? 
Yes they are mine .

Is this correct or should it be are these your books?

Comment: Without the proper context it is impossible to answer this question.

Answer (score -1):

You can test this yourself by thinking of what this sentence is a shortened version of.

Are *these* your books is short for; Are these [books] your books.

This will not work for; Are *they* your books

Answer (score -1):

Both ways are structurally and grammatically correct.

"These" is a plural form of this and can be used to refer to things. "They" can also be used to refer to things.

However if the books are near the person in the given context it may be more suitable to use "these" instead of "they".

See:
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/this

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/they

Answer (score -1):

It would be more appropriate to use the words 'these' or 'those' but there is nothing wrong grammatically in your sentence, though.

Comment: "What about those books on the table in the other room? Are they your books?" Whether the sentence is 'correct' or not entirely depends on context.